# Using Apache Solr's boost query function with Spring in Java

Tags: java, spring, solr

I'm writing a Java application that is using Apache Solr to index and search through a list of articles. A requirement I am dealing with is that when a user searches for something, we are supplying a list of recommended related search terms, and the user has the option to include those extra terms in their search. The problem I'm having, however, is that we want the user's original search term to be prioritized, and results that match that should appear before results that only match related terms.

My research suggests that Solr's boost function is the solution for this, but I'm having some trouble getting it to work with Spring. The code all runs fine and I get my search results as expected, but the boost function doesn't seem to actually be re-ordering my searches at all. For example, I'm trying to do something like this:

```
Query query = new SimpleQuery();
Criteria searchCriteria = Criteria.where("title").contains("A").boost((float) 2);
Criteria extraCriteria = Criteria.where("title").contains("B").boost((float) 1);
query.addCriteria(searchCriteria.or(extraCriteria));
```

In this example I would be searching for any document whose title contains "A" or "B", but I want to boost results that match "A" to the top of the list.

I've also tried using the Extended DisMax Query Parser with a different syntax to achieve the same result, with similar lack of success. To follow the same example pattern, I'm trying to use the expression criteria as follows:

```
Query query = new SimpleQuery();
Criteria searchCriteria = Criteria.where("title").expression("A^2.0 OR B^1.0");
query.setDefType("edismax");
query.addCriteria(searchCriteria);
```

Again I would expect this to return documents with titles matching "A" or "B" but boost results matching "A", and again it simply doesn't seem to actually affect the ordering of my results at all.

Comment: Have you checked, if the search results in the solr admin ui are as expected? So first you should determine, if it is really a problem of the spring query or a problem of solr itself.

Comment: Matthias, I have tried doing this through the Solr admin console and both of these methods do what I expect them to do: adding a boost do individual search terms (i.e. q="title:A^2 OR B") will properly boost results for A. Adding the boost query parameter also works (q="title:A OR B"&bq="title:A")

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I figured out the problem here. Elsewhere in the code someone else had added this snippet:

```
query.setPageRequest(pageable);
```

This was done to support pagination of the search results, but the pageable object ALSO contained some sort orders that looks like they got added to the query as part of the .setPageRequest method. Something to look out for in the future, it looks like sorts override boosting when working with Spring Solr queries in this scenario.